# C# Percentage Format Specifier gives different result and make assertion to fail when running in GitHub Actions

Tags: c#, .net, assert, assertion

I have a report `record` with `TaxPercentage` as `string` property.

```cs
public record SaleReportDto
{
    public string TaxPercentage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

I'm formatting the tax percentage using `C# Percentage Format Specifier`.

```cs
var report = new SaleReportDto()
{
    TaxPercentage = $"{0.18:P2}")
};
```

I'm `asserting` the above value in my test as follows,

```cs
report.TaxPercentage.Should().Be($"{0.18:P2});
```

The test passes in my `windows` machine. When I run the same in my `GitHub Actions`, I get a different result and test `assertion` fails with the following error message,

> Expected report.TaxPercentage to be "18.00 %" with a length of 7, but "18.00%" has a length of 6, differs near "%" (index 5)

So to temporarily make test pass, I have changed my `assertion` as follows

```cs
report.TaxPercentage.Contains("18");
```

Why the values differs between `assignment` and `assertion` within same machine? I use `$"{0.18:P2}"` to `assign` and `assert`. Then this should generate same value in both case. But it is not.

Any hint on why this happens? I initially thought this might be because of `Culture`, but in both places while `assigning` and `asserting` I don't use any specific `Culture`. So both places should return same value. But not sure why it doesn't work that way in `GitHub Actions`.

Comment: If you do not specify a culture you are using the default culture of the thread which executes the code. I guess this depends on OS settings. Have you tried to format the string by using a specific culture ?

Answer (score 3):

> I don't use any specific Culture. So both places should return same
> value.

That's not correct. String interpolation by default uses "current" culture for formatting, and that depends on the environment you run your program at. So on different machines it's totally possible for it to return different results. For example, on my machine your string returns third variant: `18,00 %`.

If you want to have same results on all machines this code can run at, use either invariant culture like this:

```
TaxPercentage = FormattableString.Invariant($"{0.18:P2}")
```

Or if that is not what you want - figure out which culture is used for the result you want and then explicitly use it for formatting, without relying on it to be current culture.

Comment: Just to complete your answer, which seems totally correct to me, the invariant culture is used for machine-to-machine communications usually. Viceversa, if the string is being formatted in order to display the result to humans, a proper culture (e.g.: it-IT) should be used, based on the expected audience culture.

Comment: I agree, but I believe that's what I said in the last paragraph - if invariant culture does not meet your needs - use actual specific culture which does.

Comment: @Evk I agree that its gives different result in different machine. Here then how within the same machine value differs between assignment and assertion? Both places I'm using `$"{0.18:P2}"` then it should generate same value in assignment and assertion?

Comment: @fingers10 I see I misunderstood your question. However I still believe it's related to current culture. It might change even in the same program on the same machine (for example by explicitly setting it in code). I would try to use specific culture for formatting and see if that helps.